# Adding users to group in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a group and user model joined by a membership.

When I call the code

groups/show.html.erb

`<%= link_to "Add to group", group_path(:group_id => @group.id, :user_id => user.id), :method => :put %>`

It calls the update method in the groups_controller.rb

```
def update
    @group = Group.find(params[:id])
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    if !@group.users.find(@user)
        @group.users << @user
    end
  end
```

But throws an error:

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in GroupsController#update

Couldn't find User with 'id'=1 [WHERE "memberships"."group_id" = ?]

I'm building my first rails app and don't know why this is happening. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two mistakes:

1. You need to find `@group` by `params[:group_id]`, because that is what you are sending.
2. `@group.users.find(@user)` will throw an error if `@user` is not already associated with `@group`, which is not what you want. You want to run `@group.users << @user unless @group.users.include? @user` to add a user if she isn't already in the group.

Comment: Thanks! Removing the if statement worked
That fixed the problem... but it us adding the user multiple times. Could I have a problem elsewhere?

Comment: Perfect! Bothering me all day. Great first experience of StackOverflow

Comment: Use `exists?` instead of `Array#include?` method. `include?` loads all records in the association and loops over them. `exists?` instead does a query with limit 1 to check wether the record exists or not in the association.

Answer (score 0):

Your group path uses `:group_id`  but the controller is looking for `:id`.   Those should probably match.

Comment: I tried changing it, but no joy. Either way it still shows the same error. With [WHERE "memberships"."group_id" = ?] the same in both cases. What does this line mean? I also found these debug parameters: Parameters: {"_method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"vVq5lDZK5pQori9WGc0yFKsCtIESApAW4Ep3pxDInqyTLUP7TPi0vjB6k‌​ltgJgHujWFEN2wExhU4hTOdxz/jfg==", "group_id"=>"3", "user_id"=>"1", "id"=>"3"}